# Node requests and module exports

Tags: node.js

Boa tarde galera. Alguém pode me tirar uma dúvida.
Eu tenho uma aplicação node.js com uma estr

```js
//index.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var valor = require('./valor');

app.get('/:valor', function (req, res) {
  valor.setValor(req.param.valor);
  ...
  console.log(valor.getValor());
  ...
  res.send(valor.getValor());
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});


//valor.js
let meuValor = null;
async function setValor(valor) {
  meuValor = valor;
}

async function getValor() {
  return meuValor;
}

module.exports = {
  setValor,
  getValor,
};
```

Se eu tiver uma série de requisições simultâneas cada um vai ter o retorno enviado na requisição, ou essa classe valor.js ela fica global no serviço. e um acaba pegando do outro.

Comment: Acho que, da forma que a sua classe/objeto foi construido, vai sim, ficar o valor global.

Comment: E tem como eu fazer que não seja global?

Comment: Se você criar como instância, sim... Algo como `valor = new Valor` para cada requisição.

Comment: Entendi, mas se eu precisa usar esse objeto dentro de outra classe para recuperar o valor como eu faria? Tipo se dentro do meu app.get('/:valor', function (req, res) {} eu chamasse um outro arquivo de controller para processar a requisição, como eu faria para recuperar esse valor, sem passar por parametro.